# Merge tags: [pkcs11] and [pkcs#11]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

I suggest the tags [pkcs#11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2311) and [pkcs11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs11) be merged, the wiki shows that they are talking about the same thing.

I believe that [pkcs#11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2311) is the most correct writing and would also be the one that breaks auto-completion less than the other. Hence, merging makes more sense than creating a synonym.

If I am wrong (if it is more correct to create a tag synonym than merge them), then [pkcs11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs11) should be the synonym to the master [pkcs#11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2311). This is also the tag that has the nicer wiki page.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136389/tags-for-cryptographic-algorithms-and-standards (which I've flagged for migration to this meta).

Answer (score 7):

We should be consistent with all the PKCS: currently

- [pkcs#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%231) × 20
- [pkcs#5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%235) × 27
- [pkcs7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs7) × 208
- [pkcs#8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%238) × 27
- [pkcs11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs11) × 115 and [pkcs#11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2311) × 99
- [pkcs#12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2312) × 191
- [pkcs#15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2315) × 1

That's a majority of `#` uses (if a slight one if you count questions and not tags), and I agree that PKCS#11 and the like is “more correct” — as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_11) puts it, “The correct title of this article is PKCS #11. The substitution or omission of the # is because of technical restrictions.”.

Thus, moderators: please merge

- [pkcs7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs7) → [pkcs#7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%237)
- [pkcs11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs11) → [pkcs#11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2311)

Comment: I think rename resp. merge, not synonymizing, aye?

Comment: @Deduplicator There's no rename tool in the moderator user interface, only a merge tool. If the target of the merge doesn't exist, then effectively the merge tool renames.

Comment: That's good enough. I don't insist on how they *name* it. ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to post the same question/request...is there any progress?

Comment: @vlp I'll try to get hold of a mod.